# Thermodynamics and heat

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, reversibility

To calculate irreversibility what should we use ,
 $T(∆S)$ universe or $T(∆S)$ system? In some cases the author has used system and in some cases he has calculated for universe.

[image: These are the 2 questions. In the first one the author has calculated irreversibility for only system and in the 2nd one he has calculated for universe]

Comment: Your handwriting is daunting to read, and I'm straining my neck trying to read your text sideways.  Can you please type out the problem statements and, better yet, submit each problem to a new thread (including, of course, your thoughts on how to solve them)?

Comment: Sorry mate for my writing,I'm just asking to find irreversibility where should I use T(∆S)univ.  and  where T(∆S)system

Comment: I think my answer explains this.  The terms universe.and isolated system are often considered interchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you define as your system.  For an isolated system (one for which no mass, heat, or work can be exchanged with the surroundings) the change in entropy for any process is constrained by $\Delta S\geq 0$.  Such an isolated system might consist of several sub-systems, such as a gas/cylinder/piston in conjunction with an ideal reservoir at a specified temperature $T_R$, for example.

On the other hand, for a closed system (one which can exchange heat and work with its surroundings, but no mass), the change in entropy for any process is constrained by $\Delta S\geq \int{\frac{dq}{T_I}}$, where dq is a differential heat transfer between system its surroundings during the actual process and $T_I$ is the temperature at the interface between the system and its surroundings where the heat transfer dq is occurring.  If the surroundings happen to consist of an ideal infinite reservoir at a constant temperature $T_R$, our constraint reduces to $\Delta S\geq q/T_R$.  In this case, the closed system plus the reservoir in combination represent a larger isolated system, such that $$\Delta S_{cl. sys}+\Delta S_{res}=\Delta S_{cl.sys}-\frac{q}{T_R}\geq 0$$

So, to summarize, the form of the Clausius inequality you use for a specific process depends on what you define as your system.